# Homomorphism between finite groups; showing the order of the image divides the orders of each group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have been given a question:

Let G and H be finite groups and $f:G\rightarrow H$ a homomorphism. Show that $|f(G)|$ divides both $|G|$ and $|H|$.

So I try to proceed as follows:

let K = ker(f)

then |f(G)| = |G/K| = [G : K]

(Correct? I believe this is is a consequence of the first Iso Thm.)

Now by Lagrange, the index [G:K] divides |G|. But I am at a loss trying to show that |f(G)| divides |H|. One stumbling block for me is that f is not on to, so how to I account for the other members of H?

I think a little bit of direction here could quickly help me vastly improve my understanding of this material; I have only been introduced to it over the last week or so and it is not resonating yet. Thank you for any help!

Comment: $f(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$! Apply Lagrange again...

Comment: Good news: you proved the hard part -- the other part is easier!

Comment: Just to be clear, this is why I think |f(G)| = |G/K| = [G : K]. f(K) = e (in H). So for another element of H, h1, h1 = h1*e = f(g1)*f(e) = g1K (another coset), and so on for another element of H, h2. 

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @embee33 Where is this theorem did you find it? Thanks.
I found an application of this theorem.
$N\lhd G, [G:N]<\infty, H<G, |H|<\infty, \gcd{([G:N],|H|)}=1\Rightarrow H\leq N$. c.f. Hungerford's Algebra, Exercise I.5.19.

Answer (score 11):

I think the key here is to realize that $f(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$; thus $\vert f(G) \vert \mid \vert H \vert$ by Lagrange's theorem.  Furthermore, $\ker f$ is a (normal) subgroup of $G$, with $G / \ker f$ isomorphic to $f(G)$.  Thus $\vert G \vert = [G:\ker f] \vert \ker f \vert = \vert f(G) \vert \vert \ker f \vert$, showing $\vert f(G) \vert \mid  \vert G \vert$.  In fact, we have established the tidy relationship $\vert G \vert =  \vert \ker f \vert \vert f(G) \vert = \vert \ker f \vert  \vert \text{im} f \vert$.  ***QED***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Does this reasoning work for $G=a$ where $a\in G$?

Comment: @Novice:  if $G = \langle g \rangle$ with $g^n = e$ (the identity element of $G$), $n \in \Bbb N$,, then $G$ is a finite group and the results here apply.  If $\vert G \vert$ is not finite, then concepts such as $\vert f(G) \vert \mid \vert H \vert$ may not be defined.